# How scdtype behaves when we have a new column added to the source table?

Tags: dbt, scd

We have built models for our project and it was running fine. We have scdtyp2 models created , incremental models created having all the required data.
Issue is occuring when we have a new column being added to the source table.When running the dbt models , we are getting error for scdtype2 models-It fails to recognize the new column added.
I have tried using +On-schmema-change : Sync all column configuration , but it is still giving me error .
Is there any way to accomodate new columns to the already created scdtype2 tables without droping all these tables?

Comment: When you say you have "SCD Type 2" models created, do you mean snapshots? Can you provide your code that you've used to configure these models? Snapshots should be robust to schema changes

Comment: SCD Type 2 models are same as snapshots, they store history of the changes.Snapshots is different folder outside models, but scdtype 2 are inside models folder only. They should be robust , but somehow when my base tables are changed in which these models Are bulit ,then they throw error , even though on schema change config is added, it is not working